# Bash command to sum on group

Tags: bash, sum

I am totally embarrassed to ask this but I am a total newbie on linux. I have a requirement to perform group sum on data in a text file using only bash. I have achieved some part of requirement but i am unable to get it work for a more complex sum.
Lets say I have a file tst.txt conatining data like below.

```
fruit   apple   2
fruit   orange  1
veg     carrot  4
veg     chilli  3
fruit   apple   1
fruit   orange  2
```

Now i want to get three different outputs.
One is the unique occurrence of all the fruits and vegetables.
I used below code to achieve this.

```
cut -f 2 tst.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

It gives me the output 4 which are unique values in column 2.
Now I want to sum on different groups.
I have so far got the count of groups like below.

```
sort -u tst.txt | cut -f 2 | uniq -ic
```

It gives me below output.

```
2 apple
2 orange
1 carrot
1 chilli
```

Now is the difficult part for me. I want to know how many unique fruits are there. Out put should be like this.

```
fruit 2
```

Because there are only 2 unique fruits.
I also want to sum number of fruits. That will be

```
fruit 6
```

Then i want to get highest average group. In my case it will be

```
veg 3.5
```

I would really appreciate if you guys could help me out. Solution must be working on a CSSE Linux computer.

I have came across the solutions which use `awk` or `loop` but I want to use simple command like i used earlier and strictly bash with no loops (If that's possible at all). If it cannot be achieved without external commands, then which approach is simplest?

Comment: `awk` is a great tool for this.  check it out.

Comment: `cut`, `sort`, `uniq` and `wc` are external commands just like `awk` is. Please tell us more about your requirements: why are some external commands acceptable and `awk` isn’t? None of them are _strictly_ bash.

Comment: Yes i have seen that it completely satisfies my purpose but i am not supposed to use it because its not part of standard bash? Pardon my ignorance if it came out wrong.

Comment: Dario, Thanks for enlightening me. I didn't know that these are also external commands. Let me elaborate my requirement. I have been given an assignment which says exactly "Write simple command sequences to answer the following questions:
a. how many individual/unique students are in the file?
b. which unit had the largest enrolment?
c. how many students were taking just one or just two units?
d. which unit had the highest average mark?

Comment: It also says in instructions "must be working on a CSSE Linux computer" I don't know what it means.

Comment: I installed a basic command interface in windows 10 and commands provided are working in my shell. While awk does not work. Thats why I assumed it as an external command. If i am wrong then how can i use awk?

Comment: My apologies if i am being too ridiculous. Its because I am totally new to all this and i want to learn as much as i can.

Comment: @Danny - comments aren't for discussion or additional details. You should update your original question (e.g. elaborating on your assignment). That said: in general, your question is off-topic, but there is a unix stackexchange that is probably much better suited for your question, since this is all about unix/linux command line tools, not about programming.

Comment: "CSSE Linux Computer" (*Computer Science & Software Engineering* Linux Computer" ??)

Comment: If you want to count the unique fruits, use `grep` to only get lines containing `fruit` and then `cut` to get the names without the counts. Pump that into `sort -u`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I guess it means SElinux. Nice sarcasm by the way. I think i do not fit well here with my level of knowledge. You can close the question if it is too silly for pros here.

Comment: No, that wasn't intended as a slight or offhand criticism, it just happened to be the 1st link that popped up on a search `:)` Why not `awk '/fruit/ { print $2 }' fruit.txt | sort -u | wc -l`? (where your data is in `fruit.txt`)

Comment: If you try to stay away from external commands, use `type COMMAND` to check, whether they're buildin or not. Some commands/programs exist either way, internal and external like `echo, time.` Calculating the average purely in bash isn't trivial - the bash only handles int-arithmetic which means 1/10=0 and 9/10=0. Either you have to implement int arithmetic yourself or you only work with literal fractions like 7/2 for 3.5 or 3 rest 1/2, maybe with some gcd implementation.

Comment: In the future, please try to constrain the scope of your question to things actually related to your problem. We don't need to know the parts of the same assignment you already solved -- and each StackOverflow question should surround *one* question, as opposed to having several questions related to different parts of the same assignment.